# exclude dll in msm from msi

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have a .MSI installer project created in vs2010. This .MSI includes many *.msm (merge module file). Is there a way to select specific *.msm based on different windows platform(ex: xp, win7, vista..)during installation?

For instance, if the target platform to install this .MSI is winXP, my .MSI will know what .msm to choose instead of choosing all .msm during installation.

BTW, is there a way for .MSI to access a specific *.dll which resides in .msm ? Again, for instance, if the .MSI project includes a .msm and this .msm includes many *.dll, is there a way to select a specific *.dll in .msm during installing this .MSI ?

my main purpose is to have my .MSI knowing what *.dll/*.msm to use under different windows platform during installing my .MSI.

Comment: [Merge modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/673de3ff-e58c-4153-9c8d-c3baebba5eb1) are used to deliver shared code, files, resources, registry entries, and setup logic to applications as a single compound file. In particular see the documentation about [Using Configurable Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa372408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks Mark. How about .MSI choosing specific *.msm during installation?

Comment: Merge modules are merged into the base package prior to installation using a separate merge tool. The result is a new package containing the added information.  Like the answer below suggests merge alternatives into separate features of one large package and then enable the package to select the feature to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is to assign each merge module to a new feature and set install conditions on that feature. I don't think this is possible with VS 2010 however, but there are some [commercial setup authoring tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools) that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Merge modules (.msm) are similar in structure to a simplified Windows Installer file (.msi).  A merge module cannot be installed alone, it must be merged into a .msi file. The best alternative is to obtain a freely distributed merge tool or purchase one of the merging tools available from independent software vendors. You can then use the functionality provided by [Mergemod.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/3eb087b1-0f44-40d8-a950-67d489f09408).
The intended use of merge modules was to provide a standard method for developers to deliver shared Windows Installer components and setup logic to their applications.  Merging is therefore something typically done by the author of the installation package prior to deployment.  Trying to determine and perform the correct merge when the application is being installed does not seem like the best approach.

You could instead create a separate .msi for each target platform.  Merge the appropriate .dll into each package.  Then include logic in your setup application to check the user’s system and then install the correct package.

As was suggested by the previous answer, you could merge all the .dlls into a single installation package which you have authored such that the installation of certain features and components are conditional upon [Operating System Property Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/4f516cf0-d5b3-4df6-b171-54bbafc0ef93) .

You can consider [Using Transitive Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/73677573-945f-4646-89d8-93e28f7856fe)  in your package.  The typical use for transitive components is to prepare a product to reinstall during a system upgrade. The author of the installation package specifies those components that need to be swapped out during a system upgrade as having the transitive attribute. When the user later upgrades the system, the product must be reinstalled. Upon this reinstall, the installer removes the earlier components and installs the later components, without having to install the entire product. This might serve your scenario well if you expect your users to upgrade their systems.